# 2 identical pages, one shows 403 Error

Tags: php, query-string, http-status-code-403

I have a single dynamically generated page that shows a 403 error on one particular post alone.

No 403 error: https://www.dealscafe.lk/deal/?remax-extension-cord--clicknshoplk&p=201710011409480

Have 403 error: https://www.dealscafe.lk/deal/?360-spin-mop--deals&p=201710011357340

Tried accessing the page using an online proxy, and yet it reports the same..

## Help

*This is a site that's undergoing development.

Btw, if you keep accessing that 403 Error page a few times, the server firewall blocks you. Let me know if any one of you experiences a block so I may unblock it from my end.

I've tried fixing this left and right, no clue at all as to what's causing this.

Thanks for all the help..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the first parameter after /deal/ can't start with a number.

This works: (note the 'x')
https://www.dealscafe.lk/deal/?x360-spin-mop--deals&p=201710011357340

While this doesnt:
https://www.dealscafe.lk/deal/?360-spin-mop--deals&p=201710011357340

So you should check how the $_GET parametersare handled

Comment: I can't tell for sure without seeing more of the code. But my first guess is that there's something wrong with the .htaccess file.

Comment: So it does..! You just saved the day. Any particular reason why it cannot start with a number?

Comment: This works fine... Although it starts with a number. https://www.dealscafe.lk/deal/?10-pcs-hand-tool-set--clicknshoplk&p=201710011415020